# I can not deal with the ActiveRecord android

Tags: android, activerecord, android-sqlite

i used to ActiveRecord library in my project. when my model consists of several fields, all saved properly. But if my model contains other models, I can not make the save. in more detail below:

my model(so works):

```
 @Table(name="Weathers")
    public class WeatherResponse extends Model {

        @Expose
        @Column(name="code")
        @SerializedName("cod")
        public int cod;

        @Expose
        @Column(name="base")
        @SerializedName("base")
        public String base;

        public WeatherResponse() {
            super();
        }
    }
```

but if I add a field:

```
@Expose
    @Column(name = "sys")
    @SerializedName("sys")
    public Sys sys;
```

and do so:

```
@Table(name="Weathers")
public class WeatherResponse extends Model {

    @Expose
    @Column(name="code")
    @SerializedName("cod")
    public int cod;

    @Expose
    @Column(name="base")
    @SerializedName("base")
    public String base;

    @Expose
    @Column(name = "sys")
    @SerializedName("sys")
    public Sys sys;

    public WeatherResponse() {
        super();
    }
}
```

it works conserved. my class:

```
@Table(name = "Sys")
public class Sys extends Model {
    @Expose
    @Column(name = "message")
    @SerializedName("message")
    public String message;
    @Expose
    @Column(name = "country")
    @SerializedName("country")
    public String country;
    @Expose
    @Column(name = "sunrise")
    @SerializedName("sunrise")
    public String sunrise;
    @Expose
    @Column(name = "sunset")
    @SerializedName("sunset")
    public String sunset;

    public Sys() {
        super();
    }
}
```

I found an example where the model contains an array of other models. from here I took as an example.[enter link description here](http://blog.robinchutaux.com/blog/using-retrofit-with-activeandroid/)

but how to keep in my case I do not understand.

```
public void success(WeatherResponse weatherResponse, Response response) {

                   weatherResponse.save();
                   weatherResponse.sys.save();
               }
```

Comment: First, save your sys object, then the rest

Answer (score 0):

According to this wiki https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Saving-to-the-database you need to assign the `sys` field of the `WeatherResponse` to another object like this:

```
Sys sys = new Sys();
sys.message = "something";
//another assignments
sys.save();

weatherResponse.sys = sys;
weatherResponse.save();
```

Comment: The point is that my objects are formed from JSON using Retrofit

Comment: Then you need to parse your JSON, create Sys object from it, and assign that object to weatherResponse.sys field, and then call `WeatherResponse` save() method

Comment: see the link that I wrote. it all has to do retrofit